# How to config Tomcat pooling datasource out of Spring Boot embedded one?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource

According to the Spring Boot Doc, we are suggested using Tomcat pooling datasource. If I want to deploy my Spring Boot application as a war file to a standard Tomcat server. How to config the pooling datasource? How to make Spring using the datasource which standard Tomcat provided?

Comment: As you normally would, configure the jndi lookup for that bean. The datasource will only be added by Spring Boot if none is yet available.

Comment: I think you may have misread or misunderstood the docs. The Tomcat `DataSource` is just a high-performance implementation, distributed as a library (and happens to be used in Tomcat). It's already on your classpath and you are already using it if you used the Spring Boot Starters to set up your classpath.

Comment: To Dave, do you mean Tomcat DataSource a independent project just for datasource, we can use it without Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Do a standard JNDI lookup and expose the resulting DataSource as a Bean (either via XML or Java Config).
The pooled data source can then be setup any way you like in a  element in Tomcat's context.xml

Comment: I thought the whole point of Spring Boot was to use an embedded Tomcat container, which doesn't give you access to a context.xml file, does it?

Comment: Yes that is the point, but OP specifically said that he wants to deploy to a standard Web container, not the embedded one